# How to fetch column name for each not null field of each row in a table?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am working on a table in Access which has 50 columns and 800 rows. I would like to fetch column names of each non-empty field in each row keeping the values of the first column intact e.g

### Source_Table_sample

[image]

### Result_expected

[image]

Thank you for helping me with the query.

Best regards

Comment: Which is it now? In the question you are citing Access and in the tags I see Access and Excel. Looking at the screenshots it seems to be Excel again. Could you please specify and remove all tags that do not apply?

Comment: Hi Ralph, I have the table in Excel. I have also exported the same into Access hoping it would be easier to play with data using Access. Pls feel free to suggest a solution either in Excel or Access. Thanks again for looking into it. Cheers

Comment: With 40,000 cells, you will not want formulas as they would need to be Array formulas.  Stack Overflow is not a code for me service.  If you have existing code that does not work please post it in your original post and tell us the problem with the the code.  Stack overflow is here to help with specific problems in existing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is Excel vba:

```
Sub prodname()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tws As Worksheet
    Dim oArr() As Variant
    Dim tArr() As Variant
    Dim rw As Long
    Dim clm As Long

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change to the sheet with the data
    Set tws = Sheets("Sheet2") 'change to the desired output sheet

    rw = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    clm = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    oArr = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(rw, clm)).Value
    ReDim tArr(1 To rw - 1, 1 To clm) As Variant

    For i = 2 To rw
        k = 2
        tArr(i - 1, 1) = oArr(i, 1)
        For j = 2 To clm
            If oArr(i, j) <> "" Then
                tArr(i - 1, k) = oArr(1, j)
                k = k + 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    tws.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(tArr, 1), UBound(tArr, 2)).Value = tArr
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Scott. I understand it is too late for this response. Apologies

Answer (score 0):

In Access a query of the form:

```
SELECT
    customer_name,
    IIF(product_1 IS NOT NULL, "Product_1", NULL),
    IIF(product_2 IS NOT NULL, "Product_2", NULL),
    IIF(product_3 IS NOT NULL, "Product_3", NULL),
    IIF(product_4 IS NOT NULL, "Product_4", NULL),
    IIF(product_5 IS NOT NULL, "Product_5", NULL),
    IIF(product_6 IS NOT NULL, "Product_6", NULL),
    IIF(product_7 IS NOT NULL, "Product_7", NULL),
    IIF(product_8 IS NOT NULL, "Product_8", NULL),
    IIF(product_9 IS NOT NULL, "Product_9", NULL),
    IIF(product_10 IS NOT NULL, "Product_10", NULL),
    IIF(product_11 IS NOT NULL, "Product_11", NULL),
    IIF(product_12 IS NOT NULL, "Product_12", NULL),
    IIF(product_13 IS NOT NULL, "Product_13", NULL),
    IIF(product_14 IS NOT NULL, "Product_14", NULL),
    IIF(product_15 IS NOT NULL, "Product_15", NULL),
    IIF(product_16 IS NOT NULL, "Product_16", NULL),
    IIF(product_17 IS NOT NULL, "Product_17", NULL),
    IIF(product_18 IS NOT NULL, "Product_18", NULL),
    IIF(product_19 IS NOT NULL, "Product_19", NULL),
    IIF(product_20 IS NOT NULL, "Product_20", NULL),
    IIF(product_21 IS NOT NULL, "Product_21", NULL),
    IIF(product_22 IS NOT NULL, "Product_22", NULL),
    IIF(product_23 IS NOT NULL, "Product_23", NULL),
    IIF(product_24 IS NOT NULL, "Product_24", NULL),
    IIF(product_25 IS NOT NULL, "Product_25", NULL),
    IIF(product_26 IS NOT NULL, "Product_26", NULL),
    IIF(product_27 IS NOT NULL, "Product_27", NULL),
    IIF(product_28 IS NOT NULL, "Product_28", NULL),
    IIF(product_29 IS NOT NULL, "Product_29", NULL),
    IIF(product_30 IS NOT NULL, "Product_30", NULL),
    IIF(product_31 IS NOT NULL, "Product_31", NULL),
    IIF(product_32 IS NOT NULL, "Product_32", NULL),
    IIF(product_33 IS NOT NULL, "Product_33", NULL),
    IIF(product_34 IS NOT NULL, "Product_34", NULL),
    IIF(product_35 IS NOT NULL, "Product_35", NULL),
    IIF(product_36 IS NOT NULL, "Product_36", NULL),
    IIF(product_37 IS NOT NULL, "Product_37", NULL),
    IIF(product_38 IS NOT NULL, "Product_38", NULL),
    IIF(product_39 IS NOT NULL, "Product_39", NULL),
    IIF(product_40 IS NOT NULL, "Product_40", NULL),
    IIF(product_41 IS NOT NULL, "Product_41", NULL),
    IIF(product_42 IS NOT NULL, "Product_42", NULL),
    IIF(product_43 IS NOT NULL, "Product_43", NULL),
    IIF(product_44 IS NOT NULL, "Product_44", NULL),
    IIF(product_45 IS NOT NULL, "Product_45", NULL),
    IIF(product_46 IS NOT NULL, "Product_46", NULL),
    IIF(product_47 IS NOT NULL, "Product_47", NULL),
    IIF(product_48 IS NOT NULL, "Product_48", NULL),
    IIF(product_49 IS NOT NULL, "Product_49", NULL)
FROM your_table;
```